# Bind enum to combobox and bind to property

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, enums

I have successfully passed the following Enum to a Combobox using the following:

```
public enum Color
{
    Blue,
    Green,
    Yellow
}

public Color _color { get; set; }
public Type Colors
{
    get { return typeof(Color); }
}
```

In the view I have the following:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Colors, Converter={StaticResource enumConverter}}">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding }" FontSize="14"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

This lets me pic a color in the box. What I want to do is to bind the chosen color to a property that's part of my viewmodel. I am very new to converters so I might be missing something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can bind the `SelectedItem` of the `ComboBox` to a property in your view model. The type of that property must match the type of the items generated by the `enumConverter`.

Answer (score 0):

You can bind Combobox's `SelectedItem` to the property. I rename the Property to `SelectedColor` in the ViewModel. The `PropertyChanged` event is raised in the setter, so when you update the property, for example, from another method inside ViewModel, the view is notified and updated with the new value.

```
private Color _selectedColor;

public Color SelectedColor 
{
    get { return _selectedColor; }
    set
    {
        _selectedColor = value;
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("SelectedColor"));
        }
    }
}
```

And in the XAML

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Colors, Converter={StaticResource enumConverter}}" 
    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedColor}">
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you both very much. It was actually @Joost Van Den Booms line:
 "The type of that property must match the type of the items generated by the enumConverter." that made it work.In my case I hade to change the type to string. So im going with his answer this time even though I used both of your suggestions in my project. Thank you both!

Comment: ah yes. No problem. I tried to recreate your problem so I wrote the converter where I used Enum.GetValues which returns an array of the Enum types, not strings, so the code runs smoothly.

Comment: Do you know if its possible to pass the Int-value of the enum instead of the string-name? If I could have an In-prperty on my VM that could catch it? That would be really nice.

Comment: Then you can bind to Combobox's SelectedIndex property which is an int.